# Running choreographe created behaviour from ROS

Tags: ros, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone knows how to run a behaviour created in choreographe using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130456/running-choreographe-created-behaviour-from-ros/) by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually possible by using the nao_behaviours package.

---

Originally posted by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) with karma: 106 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-27**:
can you post an example?